# react-router Link with dynamic search parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to allow my users to download a report based on a input, a checkbox or a date picker.

```
 const ReportRoute = (props) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const testObject1 = {
    name: {input},
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <input value={input} onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `api/report/name`,
            search: queryString.stringify(testObject1),
            }}
        >
          Download {props.type} report
        </Link>
      </div>
  );
};
```

I've got a Link to /api/report/name, but I cannot find how to change dynamic the search query with the value from the input.

I want two thinks :
1) If my user type "ngos" in the input, the query should be api/report/name?name=input
2) And if input is empty, the query should be api/report/name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make declare an object containing the pathname property.
The search field can be set for this object when input is not an empty string.

Finally, the object can be passed for as `to` prop value in the `Link` component.

*[View in Stackblitz playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-router-links)*

```
const Report = (props) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const testObject1 = {
    name: input,
  }

  const to = {
    pathname: 'api/report/name'
  }

  if (input !== '') {
    to['search'] = queryString.stringify(testObject1)
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <input value={input} onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
        <Link
          to={to}
        >
          Download {props.type} report
        </Link>
      </div>
  );
};
```